# What is fast way to check 'isDir' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

In my project, my program check very many dir and files.

I use python 3.8.

first, i try this.
lower is my code snippet.

```
if '.' not in filename:  # dir
```

I know, it's not right.
directory name can include '.'!

I try this.

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path_dir, filename)):  # dir
```

It's right.
but, upper code is terribly slow!

first code use 0.48 sec. but second use 17 sec...

I change [os.path.join] -> [path_dir + '\' + filename].
It takes 15 sec. it's too slow, too.

I know os.path.isdir is problem. lower is test.

```
@logging_time
def test_func1(dir_name, file_name):
    full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)
    for i in range(100000):
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            res = 'a'


@logging_time
def test_func2(dir_name, file_name):
    for i in range(100000):
        if '.' not in file_name:
            res = 'a'
```

test_func2 use just 0.003 sec, but test_func1 use 3 sec!

What is the fast way to check isDir?

Target OS is windows 10.
I don't need cross-flatform. just window.

Comment: @joshmeranda I can't find os.is_dir() . I need to import some package?

Comment: you need to import the `os` package

Comment: @joshmeranda I already import it. I use os.path.isdir now.

Comment: @Redwings: `test_func1` and `test_func2` are doing completely different things ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the fastest way to check if something is a directory is to not have to check at all. **If you wish to iterate all files in a directory tree** (you haven't actually specified whether this is the case), you should consider using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk):

os.**walk**(*top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False*)

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

The 3rd element of the tuple (`filenames`) is guaranteed to not be a directory. This is how you would print all file names in a directory tree:

```python
import os

def walk_directory(directory_name):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory_name):
        for filename in filenames:
            fullpathname = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(fullpathname)
```

Otherwise, **you should be using an `isDir` method call**. For example, if you just wanted to iterate all the files in a single directory, then one way is as follows:

```python
from pathlib import Path

def list_directory(directory_name):
    # non-recursive
    for p in Path(directory_name).glob('*'):
        if not p.is_dir():
            #filename = str(p) # to convert Path to a string
            print(p)
```

Comment: it's perfect!!! this is what i want!!
os.walk is 25 times faster than isDir! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.isdir` seems to be the fastest implementation:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import win32api
import glob
import timeit


def os_isDir(files):
    return [os.path.isdir(fullPath) for fullPath in files]

def os_NOT_isFile(files):
    return [not os.path.isfile(fullPath) for fullPath in files]

def pathlib_isDir(files):
    return [Path(fullPath).is_dir() for fullPath in files]

def winapi_GetFileAttributesA(files):
    return [win32api.GetFileAttributes(fullPath) == 16 for fullPath in files]


files = glob.glob('C:\\Windows\\System32\\*')
for func in ("os_isDir", "os_NOT_isFile", "pathlib_isDir", "winapi_GetFileAttributesA"):
    t1 = timeit.Timer(f"{func}({files})", f"from __main__ import {func}")
    print(f"Evaluation {len(files)} paths using {func} took: {t1.timeit(number=5)} seconds\n")
```

Out (on a Win7 VM):

```
Evaluation 3294 paths using os_isDir took: 2.1250754 seconds

Evaluation 3294 paths using os_NOT_isFile took: 2.7074766999999995 seconds

Evaluation 3294 paths using pathlib_isDir took: 3.4624453000000006 seconds

Evaluation 3294 paths using winapi_GetFileAttributesA took: 2.2789655999999994 seconds
```

Comment: it's little sad news. thanks for your help.